# Does USB host mode on an STM32 require VBUS sensing?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, usb-host

I’ve been using an STM32F413ZH Nucleo board as a USB host device. All is working well.

However, I’m in the process of designing my own PCB based on the Nucleo design, but using a full-size USB Type A connector as I only need to support host mode.

1. Other than having a power switch for the VBUS, do I need to enable VBUS sensing?
2. What do I do with the ID pin on the STM32; the Type A connector doesn’t have an ID pin?

Answer (score 1):

You need VBUS sensing and ID pin if you are making a dual-role ("OTG") device. If you are making a host-only, you either ignore the ID, or ground it, all depends on software stack you are using.